# AngularJS directive link function not called

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've been writing a simple angular directive to show alert when user closes the browser.

```
angular.module('myApp').directive("areYouSure", ["$window", function ($window) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        link: function() {
            alert("I am called");
            $window.onbeforeunload = function () {
                alert("I am called");
                return "are you sure?";
            };
        }
    };
}]);

<div ng-app="myApp">
<areYouSure></areYouSure>
```

Link function is not being called. what am I missing here

Comment: Are you linking the file to the page? How are your files structured?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call the directive like this,

**`<are-you-sure></are-you-sure>`**

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp',[])
 
app.directive("areYouSure", ["$window", function ($window) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        link: function() {
            alert("I am called");
            $window.onbeforeunload = function () {
                alert("I am called");
                return "are you sure?";
            };
        }
    };
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<are-you-sure></are-you-sure>
</body>
```